# IE11 not respecting height: auto

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

In Internet Explorer 11, at https://www.superiorit.com.au, the "s control" icon at top right displays with `height: 94px;`

[image]

as specified in the `img` tag:

```
<img src="https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal.png" width="375" height="94" srcset="https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal.png 375w, https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal-300x75.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 375px) 100vw, 375px" class="so-widget-image">
```

but the CSS `height: auto;` in:

```
.so-widget-sow-image-default-eef982a7180b .sow-image-container .so-widget-image {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
}
```

is not being respected by IE11. Chrome respects this CSS and reduces the height of the img to 25px tall:

[image]

How do I make IE11 display the image @ 25px tall?

Comment: Actually your CSS working fine. Because if I set width limit immediate parent or parent of parent then it is set the width as expected size. Problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `display: inline-block` style from `#siteorigin-panels-builder-9` (the container `.widget` for the topmost header elements.

This is interfering with the somewhat-fragile layout that combines float, flexbox, and `calc()` widths.

Answer (score 2):

remove  `width="375" height="94"` from `img` tag

```
<img src="https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal.png" srcset="https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal.png 375w, https://www.superiorit.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/new_connect_logo_web_normal-300x75.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 375px) 100vw, 375px" class="so-widget-image">
```

and make `width: 100%`

```
.so-widget-sow-image-default-eef982a7180b .sow-image-container .so-widget-image {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **max-height:30px**

```css
.so-widget-sow-image-default-eef982a7180b .sow-image-container .so-widget-image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  max-height:30px
}
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh. `max-height: 30px` reduces the height of the image in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. It reduces the size in chrome. I will let you know if I figure out a way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IE` specific **css**, `IE 11` supported **css** is :

```
*::-ms-backdrop,
```

Another thing you have to do is, you have to remove inline `height` and `width` attribute from `img` tag. You have to set `max-height` in your **css** class. So your code should be like

```
*::-ms-backdrop,.so-widget-sow-image-default-eef982a7180b .sow-image-container .so-widget-image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  max-height:30px
}
```

Hope this will help you.